# Unable to locate static metamodel field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What does this error mean?

```
 07:48:42,807 ERROR [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : com.lm.model.UserId_#id
```

This is how that field is defined

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Identifier<UserId> {
    @Column( name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "uuid" )
    protected UUID id;
```

Comment: isn't this a bug in Hibernate for embedded inheritance or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be bug in Hibernate itself. It is described here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8712

Answer (score 23):

I stumbled across the same issue. I don't think it is a bug.
This error occurs when you add/edit your entity model, for example a new field was added in the entity class.

To overcome this error, you have to regenerate the meta model.
Clean your project and build it again.

If using Maven, run `mvn clean` (provided that your POM is configured correctly so that it regenerate the meta model which the JPA needs).

Comment: How can we regenerate the meta model? If using Maven?

Comment: You should have the following dependency in you pom               <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Then execute mvn clean and mvn install command,                                                                                               this should regenerate canonical Meta model

Comment: What if I use gradle? I always ./gradlew cleanIdea and ./gradlew idea but these meta models don't get regenerated

Comment: So is it actually harmful if I am getting these? I only use the fields of the meta model class for the JPA criteria builder, so I add them on demand.

Comment: @jamesw1234 `./gradlew clean build`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding getter/setters to the fields on your abstract class. 
That fixed the issue for me.